# In App Engine, Is there a way to get all the children entities without including the parent Entity of the same type?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, entity, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Here's this parent-child structure of Datastore

```
+ Entity:Place,ID:1 {'name':'Derp Region','type':'region'}
|
+---+ Entity:Place,ID:1a {'name':'Derpina Province','type','province'}
|
+---+ Entity:Place,ID:1b {'name':'Banana Province','type','province'}
|
+---+ Entity:Place,ID:1c {'name':'Potato Province','type','province'}
```

and when tried to get the children places of **Derp Region**, it included `Derp Region` in the returned data like so:

```
Derp Region
Derpina Province
Banana Province
Potato Province
```

which shouldn't be the case. Is this expected due to the reason that they have the same `Entity` type?

**Insertion Code**

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Entity place = new Entity( "Place" , "1" );
place.setProperty( "name" , "Derp Region" );
place.setProperty( "type" , "region" );
datastore.put( place );

Key parentKey = KeyFactory.createKey( "Place" , "1" );

Entity placeA = new Entity( "Place" , "1a" , parentKey );
placeA.setProperty( "name" , "Derpina Province" );
placeA.setProperty( "type" , "province" );
datastore.put( placeA );

Entity placeB = new Entity( "Place" , "1b" , parentKey );
placeB.setProperty( "name" , "Banana Province" );
placeB.setProperty( "type" , "province" );
datastore.put( placeB );

Entity placeC = new Entity( "Place" , "1c" , parentKey );
placeC.setProperty( "name" , "Potato Province" );
placeC.setProperty( "type" , "province" );
datastore.put( placeC );
```

**Query Code**

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Key parentKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Place", "1" );

Query placeQuery = new Query( "Place" ).setAncestor( parentKey ).addSort( "name" , SortDirection.ASCENDING );

PreparedQuery preparedQuery = datastore.prepare( placeQuery );

for( Entity result : preparedQuery.asIterable() )
    {
    resp.getWriter().println( result.getProperty( "name" ) );
    }
```

Is there a way to get all the children entities without including the parent Entity of the same type?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Please post your query code

Comment: @GwynHowell take a look at my edits. I put there both the insertion and query code

Answer (score 0):

An 'ancestor query' is not a 'child query' - although it is similar. Think of entity groups as trees and Cloud Datastore as a Key-Tree Document database (rather than just a Key-Value or Document database).

An ancestor query is one that says "Get me every entity in this tree matching these conditions". "This tree" is the one specified by `parentKey` and your condition is "Kind = Place". Once you understand this concept, it becomes clearer how this type of query differs from a "child query".

Often, this can be ignored because `parentKey` won't match the Kind condition. This is the first solution: Make parent and children entities have different kinds - such as `PlaceRegion` and `PlaceProvince`, or if type isn't tied to parent `Place` and `PlaceChild`

The second solution is via indexing. Add an integer field called `level`, and assign it a value depending on its level in the tree. 1 = the root/parent, 2 = the immediate child. Create composite indexes including this `level` field and now you can issue queries with the condition `level = 2` to perform a child query.

The third solution is simply post filter by `key` = `parentKey` and discarding the parent.